# VBA - Offset Clarity

Tags: vba

Having trouble understanding offset.

What might be the definition difference between:

```
wsSheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

and

```
wsSheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
```

Was putting this through the immediate window, and was getting a weird error. But I get the first one gives me the number of rows in the column, but does offset go down one cell one by one?

Comment: the first is returning the last row in column A that has a value.

Comment: The second is returning the row below the last cell in column B that has a value.  `Offset` is `Offset(Row,Column)` positive on rows is down and negative up.  On columns positive is to the right and negative to the left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does offset go down one cell one by one?

It goes as many rows and/or columns you provide as parameters; using full syntax:

```
[A1].Offset(RowOffset:=1, ColumnOffset:=1).Activate    'Activates B2
[A1].Offset(RowOffset:=2, ColumnOffset:=1).Activate    'Activates B3
[A1].Offset(RowOffset:=2, ColumnOffset:=2).Activate    'Activates C3

[A1].Offset(RowOffset:=0, ColumnOffset:=0).Activate    'Activates A1
[A1].Offset(RowOffset:=-1, ColumnOffset:=0).Activate   'Error 1004 (Row 0 doesn't exist)
```

---

You should also fully qualify all ranges with `wsSheet1`:

```
wsSheet1.Cells(wsSheet1.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
wsSheet1.Cells(wsSheet1.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
```

or

```
With wsSheet1
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
End With
```

---

[image: Offset]